# Can socket.io be used to make chat application like watsapp?

Tags: javascript, php, android, networking, socket.io

I am working with chat application created in PHP and HTML/JavaScript. And it's working with simple client-server socket. But In simple client-server socket I will not manage all the criteria.

So I want to create it using [socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

I know something about it from googling :

- Socket.IO is a JavaScript library for real-time web applications.
- JavaScript framework for doing web-socket communication.
- It's a simple method to push messages from the client to the server and server to client.

But it's not useful for me.So let me know what is this? And how to work on it?
And how to create chat application using PHP, HTML And JavaScript.

Comment: Socket IO is a sort of plugin that makes websockets easier to work with, and polyfills non-supporting browsers with ajax etc. It's basically for Node.js, not PHP, and if you can't understand the excellent documentation on the [socket.IO](http://socket.io/) website, I'm not sure explaining it in a short answer would help much.

Comment: Could you give a little bit more information such as which alternatives you compared to,  and found socketio not useful.

Answer (score 2):

Socket.IO is a module used for node.js, node.js is pretty much serverside javascript. with socket.IO you can set up a websocket connection to the server enabling a bidirectional connection. instead of polling and longpolling you can send data to the client, without the client requesting it.

for more information see [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [socket.IO](http://socket.io/)